# Usage of user_id (user uuid) in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on the project that we are the primary account who have full permission, user use our service can send document to request a signature and receive the document.

In DocuSign, we have 1 account which can have multiple users under that control. So my question is what is the usage of that user? Will I use that userId to let the user send document via DocuSign, or it's just identifier and I just have to use my Integration key is enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use JWT for authentication you need that GUID to let DocuSign know who is the user you're making API calls on-behalf of.
This ID is also useful as a unique identifier for the user, juts like there's an envelopeID etc. to uniquely identify an object on the system.